# Using a loop to display answers in a quiz

Tags: python

So I am creating a quiz where the user can pick to either do geography or random knowledge and once they pick they answer five questions. I have done that part so far by adding the questions in a list and using a loop for the questions to appear and the user to input their answer I have then stored their answer in a list using append. What I'm struggling to figure out is how to to make it so that it marks each answer by saying yes correct or incorrect and then adds a point if they got it correct and I'm trying to do that by using a loop, I already have the answers stored in a list.

```
def start():

 QUIZ_CHOICE = ["G", "R"] #Geography or random knowledge

 RETAKE_QUIZ = ["Y", "N"] #Yes or No

 G_QUESTIONS = ["1. What is the capital of China?", "2. In what country is the Mekong 
 Delta?", "3. Which country uses the Rupee?", "4. Where is the river Rhine?", "5. What 
 language is the word Konnichiwa from?"]

 G_ANSWERS = ["Bejing", "Vietnam", "India", "Germany", "Japanese"]

 R_QUESTIONS = ["1. What is the seventh planet from the sun?", "2. Which actress has won the 
 most Oscars?", "3. What was the first feature-length animated movie ever released?", "4. 
 Who was Henry VIll's first wife?", "5. What was the name of the 90s sitcom starring Fran 
 Drescher?"]

 R_ANSWERS = ["Uranus", "Katherine Hepburn", "Snow White", "Catherine of Aragon", "The 
 nanny"]

 ATAWHAI_LOWER = 4
 ATAWHAI_UPPER = 6

 ID_LOWER = 4
 ID_UPPER = 6

 G_RESULTS = []
 R_RESULTS = []

 #This function asks if they will be sitting the geography quiz or random knowledge
 def quiz():
  quiz_type = input("Do you want to take the geography quiz (G) or the random knowledge 
  quiz? (R)").upper()

  return(quiz_type)

 #This part is where they complete their chosen quiz
 def complete_quiz(quiz_type):
   if quiz_type == QUIZ_CHOICE[0]:
     for G_QUESTION in G_QUESTIONS: 
       G_RESULTS.append(input(G_QUESTION))
   else:
     for R_QUESTION in R_QUESTIONS:
       R_RESULTS.append(input(R_QUESTION)


 def display(atawhai, student_id, correct_answers):
   print("Your atawhai class is {}, your student ID number is {} and you got {} answers 
   correct".format(atawhai, student_id, correct_answers))


 def main():
   atawhai, student_id = details()
   quiz_type = quiz()
   complete_quiz(quiz_type)
   if quiz_type == QUIZ_CHOICE[0]:
     correct_answers = g_responses()
   else:
     correct_answers = r_responses()
   display(atawhai, student_id, correct_answers)
   play_again = input("Do you want to retake the quiz Y or N")
   if play_again == "Y":
     start()
   else:
     print("Bye")
     exit()


 main()
```

start()

Comment: Can you use proper indentation in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your for-loops could look something like this?

```
score = 0
for question, answer in zip(G_QUESTIONS, G_ANSWERS): 
    response = input(question)
    if response == answer:
        print('You got it right!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('You got it wrong!')
```

Then at the end you can do something with the score.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single list for the answers:

```
THE_RESULTS = []

def compute_score(correct_answers, THE_RESULTS):
    score = 0
    for a, r in zip(correct_answers, THE_RESULTS):
        if a == r:
            score += 1
    return score
```